# Is vector in the span?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

So, from my understanding, a span is simply the space that can be made up of specified vectors. So if I wanted to find if vector $(1,2,3,4,5)$ was in the span of some vectors, I assume I should use gaussian elimination to sort it in row echelon form and check whether the equations are consistent.

So my matrix looks like this at the moment:

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr|r}
    1 & 2 & -1 & -1 & 3 &  1\\
    0 & 3 & 1 & 1 & -2 & 2\\
    -3 & 4 & 1 & -1 & 1 &  3\\
    1 & -4 & 2 & 2 & 2 &  4\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & -2 & 1 &  5
    \end{array}\right]$$
My workings out got very messy with the rows I chose to add and subtract, so I was wondering whether there's an trick to make the math easier when choosing to minus or add certain rows.

Answer (score 1):

In face of such questions, I usually just use a calculator to compute the determinant, which in this case is $-790$ and hence non-zero. An $n\times n$ matrix with nonzero determinant does not have zero as an eigenvalue, and hence multiplication by that $n\times n$ matrix has to be both injective and surjective, and we conclude that any vector $(a,b,c,d,e)$ lies in the image of this matrix, or equivalently the span of the column vectors of this matrix.

Comment: The op might not be familiar with linear trasnformations and eigen vectors yet. So you should just say that as the determinant is non-zero. The row vectors form a basis for $\Bbb{R}^{5}$ .

Comment: Would you saying finding the determinant is faster assuming I can't compute it?

Comment: @Tufty21 You can also solve the equation for Ax=0, if x=0 is the only solution, then the vectors are linearly independent, and hence span the entire space R^5 of dimension 5, which might be easier than solving it for (1,2,3,4,5).

Answer (score 0):

There is not trick, just to make the calculations in order to apply the Gaussian elimination in the following order
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1\color{red}{\to \boxed{1}}& 2 & -1 & -1 & 3 & | & 1\\
    0 & 3\color{red}{\to \boxed{2}} & 1 & 1 & -2 & | & 2\\
    -3 & 4 & 1\color{red}{\to \boxed{3}} & -1 & 1 & | & 3\\
    1 & -4 & 2 & 2\color{red}{\to \boxed{4}} & 2 & | & 4\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & -2 & 1\color{red}{\to\boxed{5}} & | & 5
    \end{bmatrix}$$
where the $\color{red}{\to \boxed{N}}$ denote the order of the pivoting to $\color{blue}{\to \boxed{1}}$ and all the entries under the principal diagonal are $\color{green}{\to \boxed{0}}$. Hence your approach is correct.  Also, using a bit a linear algebra theory notice that you have $5$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ and if you show that the determinant is different to zero. Then they will independent linearly and also since you have $5$ vectors in $\Bbb{R}^{5}$ so you have a basis and then of course the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\end{bmatrix}^{T}$ is in the span.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense